# GROUP CONCATing multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-concat

I'm using MySQL 5.1.66 and I came up with a select query to select all the men's shirts and their sizes and prices.  I used `GROUP CONCAT` to merge the size column and price column from their parent tables into the same column.  Here's the statement I made

```
SELECT shirts.shirt_name, shirts.men AS main_photo, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(shirt_sizes.size_name,shirt_prices.price) AS sizes
FROM shirts 
JOIN shirts_link ON shirts_link.shirt_id=shirts.id
JOIN shirt_sizes ON shirt_sizes.id=shirts_link.size_id
JOIN shirt_prices ON shirt_prices.id=shirts_link.price_id
WHERE shirts.men!='' AND shirts_link.adult='y'
GROUP BY shirts.id
```

By doing this, are the size columns and price columns still two separate entities within that one column in the select statement?  Another thing I noticed is the order of the sizes is all mixed up.  For example, this is a row from one of the columns

```
medium29.22,large29.22,1x-large29.22,2x-large30.44,small29.22,3x-large31.70
```

why isn't it going from small-3x like it's organized on the table?  I imagine in the event of what I'm trying to do in terms of injecting it into we website through PHP if it were to auto load it would go in that unorganized manner as well.  How can I fix this?

My ultimate goal here is to be able to create a selection that can auto populate each row into the javascript apps I created.  I need the load the shirt name, main picture, then each size and price into the divs I have coded for them.  Let me know if you need to see the actual tables being used.  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: ok I just updated it to show that, and I'm using MySQL 5.1.66.

Answer (score 1):

First of all purpose of group_concat function is to keep all values of a particular column in a grouped operation. For example,

```
Table1
ID   field1    field2
1     ram      science
2     ramesh   maths
1     ram      maths
```

If your requirement is to get subjects of a particular person then GROUP_CONCAT will produce then result as follows,

```
ID  field1   field3
1   ram      science,maths
2   ramesh   maths
```

Hope this gives some insight

Comment: I understand that part of it.  What I'm trying to figure out is if we do that same thing with 2 columns like I did can they still be called upon from that cell individually by referencing the column names.  Hope this helps some.

Comment: yeah they can be called. Ur only problem is they are not coming in proper order as tables??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.shirt_name, s.men AS main_photo, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(ss.size_name, '.', sp.price)) AS sizes
FROM shirts s 
INNER JOIN shirts_link sl ON sl.shirt_id = s.id
INNER JOIN shirt_sizes ss ON ss.id = sl.size_id
INNER JOIN shirt_prices sp ON sp.id = sl.price_id
WHERE s.men!='' AND sl.adult='y'
GROUP BY s.id
```